# Adding Leaflet markers to geojson data in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

Is there any possibility to apply pre-defined marker styles to geojson data. I have property 'type' defined in my geojson file and I'm trying to set marker according to type.

I have following leaflet marker defined:

```
   var chargerBlue = L.icon({
      iconUrl: iconURL + 'marker_blue.png',
      iconRetinaUrl: iconURL + 'marker_blue@2x.png',
      iconSize: [39, 52],
      iconAnchor: [19, 50],
      popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
      shadowUrl: iconURL + 'marker_shadow.png',
      shadowRetinaUrl: iconURL + 'marker_shadow@2x.png',
      shadowSize: [63, 69],
      shadowAnchor: [22, 69]
   });
```

I'm loading my geojson file:

```
   $.getJSON("elmo.geojson",function(data){
      L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
   });
```

And my geojson's structure looks following:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          24.829726,
          59.505779,
          0
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "address": "Street",
        "type": "evCharger",
        "id": 37007,
        "status": "available",
        "name": "Charger name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provide a `pointToLayer` function in the [GeoJSON options](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-option) object to create the predefined marker type you need.

```js
const options = {
  pointToLayer: (feature, latLng) => L.marker(latLng, { icon: chargerBlue })
}
const layer = L.geoJSON(data, options)
```

There is a [GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) on the leaflet site may help you.